# Error to instantiate one class in form c++

Tags: c++, forms

> I need insert one object in the linked list when i clicked a button
>   but when i make instantiate the class List this shows me one error

```
     public ref class Boletos : public System::Windows::Forms::Form
        {

        public:

            Boletos(void)
            {
                Lista *List=new Lista;
                InitializeComponent();

                //
                //TODO: Add the constructor code here
                //
            }
//*****************Click_event**********************//
...
        if (count==4){

                    Capacidad=Convert::ToInt32(line);
                    capc=Capacidad;

                    //sala->set_capacidad(Capacidad);
                    Sala *sala=new Sala();

    List->insertAlFinal(newSala(numSala,HPeli,capc,"",2000,nombrePelicula));//Here the error List undefined
                    count=0;
                }
```

Comment: add it in the place where it says, 'enter code here'

Comment: Thanks, but now when i call list from event click this show this( identifier "list" is undefined)

Comment: update your question to show the code you now have

Comment: might be an idea to mark the answer as accepted ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

u are placing your code at the wrong position, its so to say out of scope. Btw. this is not really c++, looks like c# ...

Try something like

```
Boletos(void)
{
  Lista* list = new Lista();
  InitializeComponent();
}
```

---

What u need is a class member.

```
public ref class Boletos ...
{
  public:
    ....
    void InitializeComponent()
    {
      m_lista = new Lista();
    }

  private:
    Lista* m_lista;
}
```

now u can use m_lista in all the classes member functions. What u need to understand is the concept of scope. If u declare and intialize a variable only in the scope of one function this variable is so to say lost after the program leaves the scope of this function. In the case of c++ the dynamich alloaction new Lista() without a matching call to delete would even be a memory leak.

Comment: Thanks, but now when i call list from event click this show this( identifier "list" is undefined)